# In which activity (class) constant action key should be added in Android?

Tags: java, android

I have a lot of action key in my application for example, im sending intent from activity A to activity B and i have this action key "com.mysite.COUNT". where it belong is it in Activity A or B and when you have a lot of constants that does not belong to one class, Do you make a separate file and name it constant(something) ?

Answer (score 0):

Personally I go with this approach:

```
public static class S {

    public static class intent {
        public static final int intent1 = 1; //register request
        public static final int intent2 = 2; //take a picture request
    }

    public static class result {
        public static final int result1 = 1; //user canceled
        public static final int result2 = 2; //user signed in successfully
    }

    public static class extra {
        public static final int extra1 = 1; //chosen image
        public static final int extra2 = 2; //whatever
    }
}
```

I get my constants just like I get my layouts and resources:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, S.intent.intent1);
```

Comment: Interesting, and what do you name your class that contains all of them usually (S in the example)?

Comment: I keep it S (for me it stands for Static). I prefer to keep it S and it looks like R.id.someid/R.layout.somelayout... S.prefs.push/S.extra.username...

Comment: oh and I hope I got what you meant in your question (: